# What Unix tool to quickly add/remove some text to a Python script?

Tags: python, git, unix, flask

I'm developing an application using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

I want a quick, automated way to add and remove `debug=True` to the main function call:

Development:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Production:

```
app.run()
```

For security reasons, as I might expose private/sensitive information about the app if I leave debug mode on "in the wild".

I was thinking of using sed or awk to automate this in a git hook (production version is kept in a bare remote repo that I push to), or including it in a shell script I am going to write to fire up uwsgi and some other "maintenance"-ey tasks that allow the app to be served up properly.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably [should not be using `app.run` in production](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/#deployment) (and you *definitely* don't need it [if you are using uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Quickstart)).  Instead, use one of the several deployment options discussed in the [deployment](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/#deployment) section of Flask's *excellent* documentation. ([`app.run`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.run) simply calls [`werkzeug.serving.run_simple`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple) which executes Python's included [`wsgiref`](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server) server.)

That being said, the correct way to do this is not with a post-deploy edit to your source code but with a server-specific config file that changes your settings as [@brandizzi pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10915290/135978).

You can do this in several different ways (Flask has [documentation on this too](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/) - see Armin's suggestions on [configuring from files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#configuring-from-files) and [handling the development-production switch](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#development-production)):

1. Include both your development and your server's configs in your repository.  Use an environmental variable to switch between them:

   ```
   # your_app.config.develop
   DEBUG = True

   # your_app.config.production
   DEBUG = False

   # your_app.app
   from flask import Flask
   from os import environ

   mode = environ.get("YOURAPP_MODE")
   mode = "production" if mode is None else "develop"

   config = __import__("your_app.config." + mode)

   app = Flask("your_app")
   app.config.from_object(config)
   ```
2. Store your production configuration in a separate repository along with any other server-specific configurations you may need. Load the config if an environmental variable is set.

Answer (score 12):

That is not the way to go! My recommendation is to create some configuration Python module (let us say, `config.py`) with some content such as:

```
DEBUG = True
```

Now, in our current code, write this:

```
import config
app.run(debug=config.DEBUG)
```

Now, when you run in production, just change `DEBUG` from `True` to `False`. Or you can leave this file unversioned, so the copy of development is different of the copy of production. This is not uncommon since, for example, one does not use the same database connection params both in development and production.

Even if you want to update it automatically, just call sed on the config file with the `-i` flag. It is way more secure to update just this one file:

```
$ sed -i.bkp 's/^ *DEBUG *=.*$/DEBUG = False/' config.py
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  The problem with this solution is that I want a way which is automated and I don't even have to think about- that way, I can rest assured that debug is not turned on in production without having to remember to turn it off every time I push a new commit to the remote repo.  Otherwise, my very human self might forget and leave my app vulnerable!

Comment: @ZenLikeThat Oh, I see... I expanded the answer with some suggestions - and, after all, an answer to your exact question :)

Comment: Thats what ConfigParser is for. Config files should be declarative IMO.

Comment: @sleeplessnerd Yes, it is another good possibility. I myself would prefer it most of the time. OTOH, pure-python configure files are not unusual, as one can see in Django, are a bit more straightforward and very flexible.

Comment: @brandizzi I just dont dig the concept :) - Error handling becomes hard and people will start to put code there and migration becomes hard. Also configs tend to get generated, so simple declarative formats are a win there.

Answer (score 5):

You should set up some environment variable on server. Your script can detect presense of this variable and disable debugging.

Comment: I would do it the other way around :) Put a variable on the dev machine. Secure defaults and all.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `sed`:

```
sed 's/debug=True//'
```

portable, scriptable, ubiquitous.

Comment: ...and very fragile.  Consider what happens when the file being modified contains "mydebug=TrueBlueCanary"

Comment: Yeah, its only suitable for a quick hack; not for a production mechanism for toggling environments....

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a NOCOMMIT hook (from [gitty](https://github.com/timcharper/gitty/blob/master/assets/hooks/nocommit)):

Set this as a pre-commit hook

```
if git diff --cached | grep NOCOMMIT > /dev/null; then
echo "You tried to commit a line containing NOCOMMIT"
  exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

This will prevent the commit if it contains `NOCOMMIT`.

You can of course directly replace `NOCOMMIT` by `Debug=True` in the hook.